# How to access a specific running host port from inside docker container

Tags: docker, containers, port, host

I am trying from within a Docker container to acces/share a port (7497) on the host that is already running. I am trying to "talk" to a program on the host that has a socket port running on 7497. This is setup on a unix host.

How can i expose only that specefic port for two way operation from docker when the port is alredy active on the host? Is it possible?

I cant map the port with example  -p 7497:7497, as then i get an error "bind: address already in use".  This error is correct as the port is used by the program in the host.

The only way i manage to get acces is to use --network host --userns=host in the run command when starting the container, example:

```
nvidia-docker run -e HOME=/tmp -it --rm -v /home/kc/Deep_Learning:/projects --network host --userns=host tf_py3_gpu_science:1.4
```

But this way i am exposing all ports, why i am worried for some safety issues.

Comment: Try to kill another process which using port 7497. Or you can use another port instead of 7497, `-p 7498:7497`. Then from outside, you could use localhost:7498 (Linux or Macos)

Comment: Hi, not sure i follow you. I cant kill the process running on the host as this is the communcation port. I need so to say to communication whith that port. I realise that it must be something fundamental i am missing reagading port sharing on docker, as this question is asked alot online (many post also here on stackoverflow), but i cant see that a "simple" solution is given to this..

Comment: You don't need a `-p` option to make connections out of a container; it's only needed to make connections into a container from outside.

Comment: I think I'm not follow the question too. Seem like you want to connect from your container to something that running on your host machine. This is not a common practice, but if you still want to do that, you can use `host.docker.internal` hostname to connect to your Docker host.

Comment: Thanks dave, but i need to have two way communication. I am donwloading data from the software running on the host into an application in the container, and also upploading data from the container to the host.     If i dont open up the port i cant get communicaiton at all.

Comment: @ Toan Quoc Ho, yes it is a java software that is running on the host which which has a port open for acces with an api that i am runnin from the docker container. Ok, i understand your point that this may not be so common. I am rather new to docker so I guess i am not doing it the correct way, thanks!